# How I can decrease time response from Open Office Service using JOD Converter to Print to PDF?

Tags: java, networking, pdf-generation, openoffice.org, jodconverter

We are currently using [JOD Converter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to send a word document to an open office service running in a different machine.  The open office service is being hosted in a facility were they guarantee 100 Mbps bandwidth, we have three servers that print to this server hosting the open office service.

1. Amazon Cloud server (staging) takes about 31.6 seconds to generate a pdf doc.
2. Hosting facility (development) takes about 29.5 seconds to generate the pdf.
3. Same facility (production) where the open office service is, it takes about 5.5 seconds to generate the exact same pdf doc.

But delay, latency and bandwidth are all good in terms of quality.  What can I do to decrease this response time.  It looks like the problem is the network, but I will like to have a way to measure if it is the network so I can document this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How do you serve the input (word) document to OpenOffice?  Is it uploaded to the OO server?  Do you use a network volume (NFS, SMB) as drop area?

If transferring the file first then what are you using?  Your transfer might not be optimized.  If using a network volume as drop area then the slightest network latency will hit you during random access (e.g. OO reading the input file); changing caching parameters in the NFS/SMB client might be able to help, as might be copying the file to a local volume prior to conversion.